# how to load old config.inc.php into setup

Tags: phpmyadmin

Recently I updated from phpmyadmin 4.5.3.1 to 4.7.2 on my LAMP server. In previous versions we could copy the config.inc.php file to the config directory and load it into setup to make changes. With 4.7.2 there is a new restriction that the config.inc.php file may not exist in the phpmyadmin root directory while running setup.

The docs on https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#setup "Using setup script" do not mention a "config directory" at all. I tried copying the config.inc.php file into a config dir with proper permissions, setup does not seem to recognize it. It seems that setup is now only usable from a blank configuration, so every parameter has to be manually entered from a previous configuration every time you want to use setup to build a config file or even make a single change.

So, how do you load previous configuration settings into setup?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this functionality [was removed](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/commit/f792f294f219290f3a9360788940d0e491f5d009) starting with version 4.6.6.

You can mostly just copy the `config.inc.php` over directly without needing to make any modifications (generally, new configuration directives are noted in the release notes). I know it's not the same as being able to edit it directly, but you shouldn't need to make too many modifications once your `config.inc.php` is established.

You could make a [feature request](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/new) asking for this to be brought back.